# pause animaton onhover in jquery roundrr plugin

Tags: jquery

I'm using [this plugin](http://addyosmani.com/blog/jquery-roundrr) and I have  set animation `autoplay : true`. But I want to stop the animation on `mouseover` and resume on `mouseout`, on the `roundrr_container` `div`. I tried to edit the code but could not get it done. Can you please help me with this.

Comment: http://addyosmani.com/blog/jquery-roundrr/

Comment: i cant find any animation working their.

Comment: https://github.com/addyosmani/jquery-roundrr here you get the code pls check

Comment: https://github.com/addyosmani/jquery-roundrr/blob/master/demos/demo3/index.html

Comment: https://github.com/addyosmani/jquery-roundrr/blob/master/demos/demo3/js/app.js         is the javascript

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used this, but try something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('img').hover(function() {    
        $("#roundrr_container").roundrrwheel(  
        {  
            autoplay: false  
        });
    }, function() {
        $("#roundrr_container").roundrrwheel(  
        {  
            autoplay: true 
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: the code is working bt it hide the central image and not pause the slider

Comment: https://github.com/addyosmani/jquery-roundrr/blob/master/demos/demo3/js/app.js is the javascript

Comment: https://github.com/addyosmani/jquery-roundrr/blob/master/demos/demo3/index.html is the code

Comment: $("#roundrr_container").roundrrwheel( { onSelect: function() { interfaceLock = true; } }); try this

Comment: its not working i think the do autoplay functin in the jquery.roundrr file creates the problem

Answer (score 0):

there are two event for addyosmani.

```
onImageFocus:
```

A function executed when an image has appeared under the pick when in 'pick' mode

```
onImageBlur:
```

A function that gets executed when an image is not under the pick when in 'pick' mode

and

```
hide()//Hide items
show()//show items in roundr
```

What you can do is `onImageFocus` use `hide()` event to stop animation and `onImageBlur` use `show()` to resume effect of animation.

so use Something Like this

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#roundrr_container').hover(function() {    
       $(this).roundrrwheel(  
    {  
        autoplay: false  
    });
}, function() {
    $(this).roundrrwheel(  
    {  
        autoplay: true 
    });
});
});
```

Comment: can u explain it am new in programming

Comment: have you used `<div id="roundrr_container">` as container for images?>

Comment: then try using this:
`$('#roundrr_container').hover(function () {
    $(this).hide();
  }, 
  function () {
    $(this).show();
  })`

Comment: sir its hide all my container image i really want to stop the animation. the above code hides my container image and central image is still animating

Comment: according to documentation,they have said that `hide` method overwrites previous one.try this.
`$('#roundrr_container').hover(function () { $(this).roundrrwheel('autoplay','false'); }, function () { $(this).roundrrwheel('autoplay','true'); })`

Answer (score 0):

atlast the problem solved by

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {                                     $('.my_class').mouseover(function(event)                                                            {                                                                   ap=1;                                                               });                            $('.my_class').mouseout(function(event)                                                              {                                                                   ap=0;                                                                   });
});
</script>`
```

and then it checked on the jquery.roundrr.js page

first declared variable ap in page top before function declaration then changed the code at  function switchitems loop to

```
function switchItems($m, remove, add, posOffset, direction){if(ap==0){
    if(remove==add) add = remove - 1; 
    var $remove = $($m.raditems()[remove]); 
    var toAddto = $m.raditems()[add]; 
    if(remove>add) $remove.insertBefore(toAddto);
    else $remove.insertAfter(toAddto);
    animateWheel($m,posOffset, direction); }};`
```